# Are there any free alternatives to Silktest?

Tags: user-interface, testing, automation, silktest

Does anyone know if there are any (ideally free) alternatives to [SilkTest](http://www.borland.com/us/products/silk/silktest/index.html) for automated GUI application testing?

**[Edit]** This is a Windows-only GUI written in C++/CLI if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

selenium might be useful

[OpenSTA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensta/)

[Autonet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/autotestnet/)

[Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/pg?id=Products&category=squish&sub=overview&subsub=overview)

[GNU/Linux Desktop (GUI Application) Testing Project (GNU LDTP)](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

Have the look on this 
http://www.opensourcetesting.org . U can find some thing over there

Comment: Selenium appears to be a web-app tester?

Comment: OPEN STA is web and application testing

Comment: Excellent - I'll have a look at those :-)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows app, you can use [pywinauto](http://pywinauto.openqa.org/). It doesn't have the capability to record user actions like Silk but I think that it is a nice alternative for Windows applications. Python seems to me a much better choice than the 4Test language.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) can be another option.